# Call MapDispatchToProps methods in Functional Components

Tags: reactjs

I would like to call 'mapdispatchtoprops' methods into the functional component. But, it is not working as expected"
I have shared some code.

I have created one functional component. here my code

### loadHelpers.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {loadShowInfo,getCurrentSlug } 
from '../../actions/requesthandler'

export const loadHelpers= (isManualAccess) =>{
  loadShowInfo(isManualAccess)
  return null
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        loadShowInfo: (show_info_slug, modeType, season_slug) => dispatch(loadShowInfo(show_info_slug, modeType ,season_slug)),
        getCurrentSlug: (currentslug,slugurl) => dispatch(getCurrentSlug(currentslug,slugurl))
    }
};

export default connect(null , mapDispatchToProps)(loadHelpers);
```

**loadShowInfo method contains multiple axios calls.**

### ShowInfo.js

I have called the functional method here.

```
import {loadHelpers} from '../common/loadHelpers'

loadDatas = (isManualAccess = false , seasonId = "") => {
        this.props.loadHelpers(isManualAccess)
    }

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        loadHelpers: () => dispatch(loadHelpers()),
    }
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShowInfo)
```

Expected Result:
 How to call the functional method into another functional component?

Comment: Functional component will be called as any other react component. `return <LoadHelpers isManualAccess={isManualAccess} />`

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify loadHelpers. https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html